# Why can I initialize this column with a NULL value, but I can't update it as such?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database-design

**Situation:**

I have 2 tables, created with

```
$wpdb->query("
CREATE TABLE projs 
    (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    compname VARCHAR (200), 
    projname VARCHAR (200), 
    imageurl VARCHAR(300), 
    sumsmall VARCHAR (250), 
    sumfull VARCHAR (5000), 
    results VARCHAR (5000), 
    postdate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    caseid MEDIUM INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (caseid) 
        REFERENCES cases(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    ) $charset_collate
");
```

and

```
$wpdb->query("
CREATE TABLE cases 
    (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    compname VARCHAR (200), 
    casename VARCHAR (200), 
    imageurl VARCHAR(300), 
    summary VARCHAR (5000), 
    results VARCHAR (5000), 
    postdate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) $charset_collate
");
```

The relationship between them is that each project (a row in the `projs` table) can have an associated case case study (a row in the `cases` table); hence, the

```
caseid MEDIUM INT, FOREIGN KEY (caseid) REFERENCES cases(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

in the initialization of the `cases` table.

I have a PHP function to handle AJAX calls made from admin panel I created. It is for adding, updating or deleting a project.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_proj_update', 'proj_update' );

function proj_update ( )
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $compname = $_POST['compname'];
    $projname = $_POST['projname'];
    $imageurl = $_POST['imageurl'];
    $sumsmall = $_POST['sumsmall'];
    $sumfull = $_POST['sumfull'];
    $results = $_POST['results'];
    $caseid = (!isset($_POST['caseid']) || strcmp($_POST['caseid'],'none')) ? $_POST['caseid'] : "null";

    $thisAction = $_POST['thisAction'];

    $message = "";

    switch ($thisAction)
    {
        case 'add':
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $message .= $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO projs (compname,projname,imageurl,sumsmall,sumfull,results,caseid) VALUES (" . implode(",", array("'$compname'", "'$projname'", "'$imageurl'", "'$sumsmall'", "'$sumfull'", "'$results'", "$caseid")) . ")") 
                        ? 'Successfully added project ' . $projname . ' to the database.'
                        : 'Error occurred when trying to add project to database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        case 'delete':
        {
            global $wpdb; 
            $message .= $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM projs WHERE id=" . $id)
                      ? 'Successfully deleted project from the database.'
                      : 'Error occurred when trying to delete project from database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        case 'update':
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $message .= $wpdb->query("UPDATE projs SET compname='$compname',projname='$projname',imageurl='$imageurl',sumsmall='$sumsmall',sumfull='$sumfull',results='$results',caseid='$caseid' WHERE id=$id")
                        ? 'Successfully updated project.'
                        : 'Error occurred when trying to update project in database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            $message .= 'Didn\'t recognize action.'; 
            break;
        }
    }
    die($message);    
}
```

I've tested the `add` part of the function and haven't experienced any failures, but I have been getting an error whenever I try to `update` a `caseid` to be `null`. The error statement generated by my script above when I try to do this is

> Error occured when trying to trying to update project in database:
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('my_database_name'.'projs',CONSTRAINT 'projs_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY
>   ('caseid') REFERENCES 'cases' ('id') ON DELETE SET NULL

**Question:**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: null back to a PK null won't work, cuz PK can't be null in parent table ? That sorta thing ? Or 'null' is not there ?

Comment: @Drew Ahh ... I thought `null` in SQL was in any other language -- it literally refers to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: null is not 'null' ... null is not "null".... in fact, null<>null,  but null is null, as in `select null is null;` yields 1

Comment: @MediocreWebDev this code should be feared... you should never, ever, ever, ever, ever use string concatenation or variable interpolation to craft a query. Use. Prepared. Statements. There are no excuses.  There are security vulnerabilities in your code that are painfully trivial to exploit.  e.g, an update setting the "compname" to `pwn3d' --` for one row would almost certainly set *all* of them to the same value, "pwn3d"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., "$caseid")
```

which means your query is actually running

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., "null")
```

That's not an SQL null. It's a STRING with the characters `n`, `u, etc...

If you want to insert an actual SQL null, you'll have to do the value quoting elsewhere:

```
$caseid = (isset stuff) ? "'" . $_POST['caseid'] . "'" : "null";
                          ^^^^^------------------^^^^^-- add quotes here

$message .= $wpdb->query([..snip..], $caseid)) . ")") 
                                    ^-------^---no quotes here
```

Comment: You need to escape $_POST values -- to handle quotes and to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your query is that you are assigning the string "null" to your project's `caseid`.

You should do something like:

```
$caseid = (!isset($_POST['caseid']) || strcmp($_POST['caseid'],'none')) ? "'" . $_POST['caseid'] . "'" : "null";
```

And then, in your query:

```
case 'update':
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $message .= $wpdb->query("UPDATE projs SET compname='$compname',projname='$projname',imageurl='$imageurl',sumsmall='$sumsmall',sumfull='$sumfull',results='$results',caseid=$caseid WHERE id=$id")
                        ? 'Successfully updated project.'
                        : 'Error occurred when trying to update project in database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
            break;
        }
```

Notice that `caseid` is not wrapped in single quotes any more because i am adding those single quotes when defining it.